# Alpha equivalence between variables in lambda calculus

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

Just a fairly simple question (so it seems to me). If two variables `(x)(x)` are alpha equivalent. Is `(x1x2)(x2x1)` alpha equivalent?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand your question. Are you asking whether `x1 x2` is alpha-equivalent to `x2 x1`?

Comment: basically yes, I am confused as lecturers told us that x1 x1 are equivalent same with x1x2 x1x2.

Comment: Any lambda term is always equivalent to itself, so in particular `x` is equivalent to `x`. But `x1 x2` is not alpha equivalent to `x2 x1`. I'm not sure I get your point.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two terms are alpha-equivalent iff one can be converted into the other purely by **renaming bound variables**.

A variable is considered to be a **bound variable** if it matches the parameter name of some enclosing lambda. Otherwise it's a **free variable**. Here are a few examples:

```
λx. x          -- x is bound
λx. y          -- y is free
λf. λx. f x y  -- f and x are bound, y is free
f (λf. f x)    -- the first f is free; the second is bound. x is free
z              -- z is free
```

Basically, "bound" and "free" roughly correspond to the notions of "in scope" and "out of scope" in procedural languages.

Alpha-equivalence basically captures the idea that it's safe to rename a variable in a program if you also fix all the references to that variable. That is, when you change the parameter of a lambda term, you also have to go into the lambda's body and change the usages of that variable. (If the name is re-bound by another lambda inside the first lambda, you'd better make sure not to perform the renaming inside the inner lambda.)

Here are some examples of alpha-equivalent terms:

```
λx. x   <->   λy. y   <->   λberp. berp
λx. λf. f x   <->   λx. λg. g x   <->   λf. λx. x f   <->  λx1. λx2. x2 x1
λf. λf. f f   <->   λg. λf. f f   <->   λf. λg. g g
```

So is `x x` alpha-equivalent to `x1x2 x1x2`? **No!** `x` is *free* in the first term, because it's not bound by an enclosing lambda. (Perhaps it's a reference to a global variable.) So it's not safe to rename it to `x1x2`.

I suspect your tutor really meant to say that `λx. x x` is alpha-equivalent to `λx1x2. x1x2 x1x2`. Here the `x` is bound by the lambda, so you can safely rename it.

Is `x1 x2` alpha-equivalent to `x2 x1`? For the same reason, **no**.

And is `λx1. λx2. x1 x2` equivalent to `λx1. λx2. x2 x1`? Again, **no**, because this isn't just a renaming - the `x1` and `x2` variables moved around.

However, `λx1. λx2. x1 x2` **is** alpha-equivalent to `λx2. λx1. x2 x1`:

1. rename `x1` to some temporary name like `z`: `λz. λx2. z x2`
2. rename `x2` to `x1`: `λz. λx1. z x1`
3. rename `z` back to `x2`: `λx2. λx1. x2 x1`

Getting renaming right in a language implementation is a fiddly enough problem that many compiler writers opt for a *nameless* representation of terms called *de Bruijn indices*. Rather than using text, variables are represented as a number measuring how many lambdas away the variable was bound. A nameless representation of `λx2. λx1. x2 x1` would look like `λ. λ. 2 1`. Note that that's exactly the same as the de Bruijn representation of `λx1. λx2. x1 x2`. de Bruijn indices thoroughly solve the problem of alpha-equivalence (although they are quite hard to read).