# How to evaluate the following lambda expression?

Tags: python, lambda

The following is a question I have on lambda expressions:

```
def combinator(y):
    return (lambda x: lambda y: x(y))(lambda x:y)

Evaluate the following expression combinator(lambda x: x*10)(11)(12).
```

I understand that return statements return a value so perhaps, we should start by simplifying the lambda expression of the return statement:

```
(lambda x: lambda y: x(y))(lambda x:y) simplifies to (lambda y: (lambda x:y)(y)),

which further simplifies to (lambda y: y)
```

However, following the above logic would lead me to the wrong answer. The answer is 120.

I would like to ask, what is the method to deal with the above lambda expression?

Comment: You don't simplify functions like equations. You expand them with substitution. For example, the call to `combinator()` passes a lambda function as `y` which you then substitute leading to `(lambda x: lambda y: x(y))(lambda x:lambda x: x*10)(11)(12)`

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the reply. May I know why you only substituted into the y of the 2nd part of the expression and not the "y"s in the first part of the expression?

Comment: I was just showing you the first step. You continue substituting until you get an expression.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks! Will attempt to do it with your method

Comment: Also confusing is the the definition of `combinator` has two different variables named `y` in it, and you need to know which is which.  The `lambda y: x(y)` should probably be easier to understand as `lambda z: x(z)`, since it has no relationship to the `y` that's the argument to the function.

Comment: @FrankYellin Why do you say that the "y" in lambda y: x(y) has no relationship to the y of the function?

Comment: @FrankYellin Is this something to do with alpha conversion?

Comment: Cause that's what lambda does.  It binds a variable to a value within a scope.

Comment: Related: "[What are Free and Bound variables?](//stackoverflow.com/q/21855838/90527)", "[What is meant by 'Capture-avoiding substitutions'?](//stackoverflow.com/q/11239262/90527)"

Answer (score 1):

> (lambda x: lambda y: x(y))(lambda x:y) simplifies to (lambda y: (lambda x:y)(y)),

No. `y` is free in `(lambda x:y)`, so applying `(lambda x: lambda y: x(y))` by simply substituting the expression for `x` results in [variable capture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11239262/90527). If you are going to simplify the expression, you must first rewrite `(lambda x: lambda y: x(y))` to an [alpha-equivalent expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47762178/90527) that has no bound variables with the same names as free variables of `(lambda x:y)` to avoid the capture. How to do this is left as an exercise.